# Printing the body of a message

Tags: java, email, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am trying to make a program that will neatly print all the bodies of the messages of my inbox yet exchange web services is making it difficult.  I seem to have easy access to everything except the body of the message.  This is what I'm doing right now

```
static final int SIZE = 10;
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);

ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("USERNAME","PASS");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setUrl(new URI("https://MY_DOMAIN/ews/exchange.asmx"));

ItemView view = new ItemView (SIZE);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);
System.out.println(findResults.getItems().size() + "Messages");


for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    try {
        Item item = findResults.getItems().get(i);
    System.out.println("SUBJECT: " + item.getSubject());
    System.out.println("TO: " + item.getDisplayTo());
    System.out.println("BODY: " + item.getBody().toString());


    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        break;
    }


}
```

Of course, I have my credentials and domain filled out fittingly for my code.  When I run this I get this message though.

```
Exception in thread "main" microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceObjectPropertyException: You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.PropertyBag.getPropertyValueOrException(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.PropertyBag.getObjectFromPropertyDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Item.getBody(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Line 26 is the line where I try to print the body. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out actually.  It looks like ExchangeService will close the connection after it is done pulling the needed info.  to fix this I made a function

```
private static ExchangeService getService() throws Exception {
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("USERNAME","PASS");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    service.setUrl(new URI("DOMAIN"));
    return service;
}
```

I then call load like so

```
getService().loadPropertiesForItems(findResults, itempropertyset);
```

Where I define itempropertyset as such

```
PropertySet itempropertyset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
itempropertyset.setRequestedBodyType(BodyType.Text);
view.setPropertySet(itempropertyset);
```

Answer (score 2):

The FindItem operation doesn't return the  Body of a Message so you need to make a separate GetItem Request to the server to get this. In the Managed API you should be able to use Load method to do this so just change

```
Item item = findResults.getItems().get(i);
item.Load()
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: It gives me this Http connection error but still pulls the number of emails in my inbox.    Exception in thread "main" microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EWSHttpException: Connection not established

Comment: The Connection not established is a know error in the Java API, to fix this you need to patch the code yourself see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc018f5f-56ef-43ea-8bee-ce52760589b7/e2010-ewsja-java-windows-server-2003-email-having-null-character-in-subject?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Comment: I went without HTML. it has any method for that ??